# Use a Select Min and MAx in your where clause

Tags: sql, max, where-clause, min

I am using a number of select statements to drive results, however I have 2 select statements which returns the minimum time for appointment and max time for appointment. However where the min and max are the same, I want to remove from within my where clause.

```
SELECT
  APPOINTMENTS.userid,
  users.LOCATIONID,
  MIN(APPOINTMENTTIME) AS mintime,
  MAX(APPOINTMENTTIME) AS maxtime

FROM appointments
WHERE APPOINTMENTDATE BETWEEN '2017-01-07' AND '2017-01-07'
AND NOT mintime <> maxtime
GROUP BY appointments.USERID,
         users.LOCATIONID,
         appointments.APPOINTMENTDATE
```

I get the error Mintime is not valid.

I am sure I need to hold this in a new sub select but not sure..

Cheers

Comment: Left justified SQL is too hard to read...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`HAVING` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql) is used for aggregate functions, e.g.

```
HAVING NOT MIN(APPOINTMENTTIME) <> MAX(APPOINTMENTTIME)
```

I don't know why you are using a double negative in your predicate though, based on your description you just need `<>`

```
HAVING MIN(APPOINTMENTTIME) <> MAX(APPOINTMENTTIME)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and that worked perfect. Not used Having before. Will do some research on that function.. Always learning :-) thanks Garethd

Answer (score 1):

Try this as per Sql Server

```
        SELECT * FROM (
        select   
        APPOINTMENTS.userid, 
        users.LOCATIONID,
        min(APPOINTMENTTIME) as mintime, 
        max(APPOINTMENTTIME) as maxtime
        from appointments
        where 
        APPOINTMENTDATE between '2017-01-07' and '2017-01-08'

        group by 
        appointments.USERID,users.LOCATIONID,
        appointments.APPOINTMENTDATE
        )as t WHERE  mintime <> maxtime
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
select   
APPOINTMENTS.userid, 
users.LOCATIONID,
min(APPOINTMENTTIME) as mintime, 
max(APPOINTMENTTIME) as maxtime

from appointments
where 
APPOINTMENTDATE between '2017-01-07' and '2017-01-07'

group by 
appointments.USERID,users.LOCATIONID,
appointments.APPOINTMENTDATE
having min(APPOINTMENTTIME)  <> max(APPOINTMENTTIME)
```